# Fuzzy SVG Rendering

Tags: google-chrome, svg, fonts, safari, rendering

I have trouble figuring out an issue I've been having with svg->font conversion.

Using Inkscape, I created a new svg (dimensions - 1000x1000) that has a shape star using the draw tool in the rectangular path create mode.

The path I used to create is this:

```
 bottom left -> top center -> bottom right -> left top -> right top -> left top
```

Here's the created file: [star.svg](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63407666/star_test/star.svg). There's no issue with this file so far.

Now, I've used [fontcustom](http://fontcustom.com/) to compile this svg into a font, and you can look at the generated preview [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63407666/star_test/fontcustom/fontcustom-preview.html).

This preview looks differently in Safari vs Chrome (or Firefox or Opera). But there's a filled area in all of them. You can check the preview link yourself, or here's the screenshots of how it looks:

Chrome:

[image: chrome screenshot]

Safari:

[image: safari screenshot]

Why's this fill area coming in the first place? Why is it different in browsers?

---

A bit of context:

The actual issue is much bigger. I've a set of svgs created by someone in Adobe Illustrator, some of which are glitchy in similar fashion (unwanted fill) in chrome and other browsers. Safari and webkit2png somehow render the svg fonts correctly. So I tried to recreate the process in above mentioned steps.

More context:

I've also used icomoon app which many suggested, and it just gives blank glyphs for some reason.

Comment: is there a fill-rule set (or should be one set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases, font glyphs are composed of **filled shapes**.  They don't use the stroke (line).  So when your SVGs are being converted to a font, the font SVGs are getting a fill applied, even if they didn't have one before.

The differences between browsers is probably explained by the fact that each browser may be loading a different generated font type.  Eg. woff vs TTF etc.

The fix is to design your SVGs so that they only use filled shapes and **don't** rely on strokes (ie. line colour, width etc).  If you follow the following rules, your glyphs should always work when converted:

1. Keep your line colour as "none" or "transparent",
2. Never use any fill colour except black (ie. don't use "white" to make holes)
3. Never let shapes cross over themselves or other shapes.

So, for example, in the case of your star, it should be designed as a filled star shaped object with a star shaped hole in it.